# How do I declare an instance of a class within a struct?

Tags: c++, oop

```
Class className{ ... 

struct vec
{   string name;
    className value;
};
```

above are my class and struct definitions, my class object is supposed to be the value part of the struct

I've tried many things: (for ex)

```
vecName.value = className hey;
```

but nothing.. this shouldn't be very hard, but i find myself struggling.. anyone? thanks

Comment: why do you need vec to be a part of className?

Comment: You're going to get a lot of seriously crazy answers to this question until you edit it so that it makes sense.  Be more clear about what you're attempting, what your error was, etc..

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very well-formed, but here's something that compiles and works, and you can probably extract the information you need from it

```
#include <string>

class ClassName {
    // your code
};

struct vec
{
    std::string name;
    ClassName value;
};

int main() {
    vec v;
    ClassName yourclass;
    v.name = "hey";
    v.value = yourclass;
}
```

However, while this works there are several things about this code that could be considered "bad practice".

First of all, you should probably make *vec* a class and not a struct, and give it a proper constructor, make name and value private, etc.

So here's a slightly better example:

```
#include <string>

class ClassName {
    // your code
};

class Vec
{
public:
    Vec(const std::string &name, const ClassName &value)
    :   name_(name), value_(value) {}

    const std::string& getName() { return name_; }
    const ClassName& getValue() { return value_; }

    void setName(const std::string &name) { name_ = name; }
    void setValue(const ClassName &value) { value_ = value; }

private:
    std::string name_;
    ClassName value_;
};

int main() {
    ClassName yourclass1;
    Vec v("hey", yourclass1);
}
```

It's still not perfect because:

1. Every time you copy a Vec, you (still) also copy your class. This may be fine, depending on your application, but it could also slow down your application if your class is very big. In that case you may want to store a pointer or a smart pointer (like [boost::shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm)) to your class.
2. I just provided getX() and setX(). It's better if you can come up with functions that do logical things instead of purely getting/setting the value, like a Dog class might have run() and jump() and getHappiness()

However, these are things that depend on what you're trying to do, so you'll have to do them yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry for the poorly asked question, I will make an effort to ask better questions in the future.

Comment: This is all for an assignment.  We're supposed to maintain a vector of structs, and the value part of the struct is an instance of a class.  In the class I have overloaded operators (=, -, +) and now when i put " v.value = yourclass; ", g++ tells me "undefined reference to `strSet::operator=(strSet const&)'" .. now i'm really confused

Comment: Looks like that class strSet doesn't provide copy constructor. (Is class `ClassName` contains member of strSet type?)

Comment: @Rima - I can't really say how to fix it without knowing more context. You say it's for an assignment, so the code is probably not too long. Would you want to post it on a site like http://codepad.org/?

Comment: Oleg, yes it does.

Migi, one moment.

Comment: @Migi

here is my class definition: http://codepad.org/UuVO3S66
(do you need implementation?.. strSet constructor clears the strVector is pretty much it right now)

here is the part of my main that is causing problem: http://codepad.org/9Gd0Xyzt

Comment: @Rima - Well, I'm not sure yet, but it's very confusing that you have 2 variables named "set" in main, one is a string the other a strSet. But the actual error is probably this: you have a strSet.cpp file (right?) and a main.cpp, and try to compile main.cpp without telling g++ about the code in strSet.cpp. Are you using a makefile?

Comment: The double variable part i was going to change, but couldn't really think of a way since im reading input in.. hmm

Comment: makefile was provided to us by the prof, so it should be correct, it's been compiling my code before this problem too. i just removed the double variable thing, and put some arbitrary name's to test, and it's still giving me that operator error

Comment: yea, I didn't expect it to solve the problem. But in that case, can I see strSet.cpp (if it exists)? My best guess would be that it's a problem in the definition of strSet::operator=().

Comment: I didnt even implement the = operator yet.  when i comment the definition of it out in my .h file, my code compiles fine.. weird

Comment: heres the assignment if you wanna check: http://plg.uwaterloo.ca/~holt/cs/246/2011/asgn04/asgn04.doc

Comment: @ Rima ah yes, that explains it: the error basically says it can't find strSet::operator=(), which is logical since it isn't there! :) So you'll have to write strSet::operator=() first, because this code makes use of it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to set a instance of `className` to `vecName.value`?

```
className instance;

vecName.value = instance;
```

Or if you only want to set `vecName.value` to a new instance of `className`:

```
vecName.value = className();
```